# To do value conversion both ways in android app

Tags: java, android

Im building a converter app and it's to convert centimetres into inches but i want it to do the opposite too, so the user can enter a value into either box to convert it. Ive tried various ways but won't work.

Here's my src code

```
package com.qub.buildersbuddy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CentInch extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cent_inch);

        final EditText editCentimeters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCentimeters);

        final EditText editInches = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editInches);

        Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);

        buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                double centimeters = Double.valueOf(editCentimeters.getText()
                        .toString());

                double inches = centimeters * 0.393700787;

                editInches.setText(String.valueOf(inches));

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry , typo it currently converts centimetres to inches and I want it to do the opposite too, thanks.

Comment: check for default values or empty fields. if inches field is empty , try converting centimeters to inches and vice versa. need to handle both field empty , both field having values in your own way.

Comment: you can edit your question..

Answer (score 0):

I know little about android but try to make something like this:

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    double centimeters = 0;

    double inches = 0;

    //convert inches to centimeters
    if(editCentimeters.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        inches = Double.valueOf(editInches.getText().toString());
        //do the conversion
        editCentimeters.setText(String.valueOf(inches));
    }
    //convert centimeters to inches
    else if(editInches.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        centimeters = Double.valueOf(editCentimeters.getText().toString());
        //do the conversion
        editInches.setText(String.valueOf(inches));
    }

}
```

if `isEmpty()` doesn't work try with `.equals("")` or `== ""`. You get the point